# What is inexact steepest descent method

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Is there anybody knowing what is the inexact steepest descent method for solving non-linear optimization problems? Any reference or formal definition available online? I was asked by someone, but didn't find the best answer. I think it should be an variation of the steepest descent method, but not sure.

Hope to get some ideas..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> In this method are admitted relative errors on the search directions, more precisely, an approximation
>   of the exact search direction is computed at each iteration.

<sup>[arXiv:1207.0775 [math.OC]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0775)</sup>

(Also) see [Fliege and Fux Svaiter: "Steepest Descent Methods for Multicriteria
Optimization" (PDF)](http://w3.impa.br/~benar/art/fli-sva00.pdf).